# Tensorflow application keeps increasing memory usage

Tags: python, tensorflow, memory, memory-leaks

We are running the following tensorflow code, the problem is that the memory usage keeps increasing and at about Epoch 30 (more than an hour) it runs out of memory and stops. Any suggestion?

I've tried to use gc.collect() at the end of each iteration; tried to see in the Variable Explorer of Spyder is any variable goes out of bounds but their size remains the same for the whole execution of the program.

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    data_dir = "./datasets/monet2photo/"
    batch_size = 1
    epochs = 500
    mode = 'train'

    with tf.Session() as sess:

        if mode == 'train':
            imagesA, imagesB = load_images(data_dir)

            image_size = 128
            input_c_dim = 3
            output_c_dim = 3

            pool = ImagePool(max_size)

            real_data = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,
                                       [None, image_size, image_size, input_c_dim + output_c_dim],
                                       name='real_A_and_B_images')

            real_A = real_data[:, :, :, :input_c_dim]
            real_B = real_data[:, :, :, input_c_dim:input_c_dim + output_c_dim]

            fake_B = generator(real_A, options, False, name="generatorA2B")
            fake_A_ = generator(fake_B, options, False, name="generatorB2A")
            fake_A = generator(real_B, options, True, name="generatorB2A")
            fake_B_ = generator(fake_A, options, True, name="generatorA2B")

            DB_fake = discriminator(fake_B, options, reuse=False, name="discriminatorB")
            DA_fake = discriminator(fake_A, options, reuse=False, name="discriminatorA")

            g_loss_a2b = criterionGAN(DB_fake, tf.ones_like(DB_fake)) \
                + L1_lambda * abs_criterion(real_A, fake_A_) \
                + L1_lambda * abs_criterion(real_B, fake_B_) \
                + 0.5 * abs_criterion(generator(real_B, options, True, name="generatorA2B"), real_B)
            g_loss_b2a = criterionGAN(DA_fake, tf.ones_like(DA_fake)) \
                + L1_lambda * abs_criterion(real_A, fake_A_) \
                + L1_lambda * abs_criterion(real_B, fake_B_) \
                + 0.5 * abs_criterion(generator(real_A, options, True, name="generatorB2A"), real_A)
            g_loss = criterionGAN(DA_fake, tf.ones_like(DA_fake)) \
                + criterionGAN(DB_fake, tf.ones_like(DB_fake)) \
                + L1_lambda * abs_criterion(real_A, fake_A_) \
                + L1_lambda * abs_criterion(real_B, fake_B_) \
                + 0.5 * abs_criterion(generator(real_B, options, True, name="generatorA2B"), real_B) \
                + 0.5 * abs_criterion(generator(real_A, options, True, name="generatorB2A"), real_A)
             # generatorBId and then generatorAId

            fake_A_sample = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,
                                           [None, image_size, image_size,
                                           input_c_dim], name='fake_A_sample')
            fake_B_sample = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,
                                           [None, image_size, image_size,
                                           output_c_dim], name='fake_B_sample')

            DB_real = discriminator(real_B, options, reuse=True, name="discriminatorB")
            DA_real = discriminator(real_A, options, reuse=True, name="discriminatorA")
            DB_fake_sample = discriminator(fake_B_sample, options, reuse=True, name="discriminatorB")
            DA_fake_sample = discriminator(fake_A_sample, options, reuse=True, name="discriminatorA")

            db_loss_real = criterionGAN(DB_real, tf.ones_like(DB_real))
            db_loss_fake = criterionGAN(DB_fake_sample, tf.zeros_like(DB_fake_sample))
            db_loss = (db_loss_real + db_loss_fake) / 2
            da_loss_real = criterionGAN(DA_real, tf.ones_like(DA_real))
            da_loss_fake = criterionGAN(DA_fake_sample, tf.zeros_like(DA_fake_sample))
            da_loss = (da_loss_real + da_loss_fake) / 2
            d_loss = da_loss + db_loss

            model_vars = tf.trainable_variables()
            d_A_vars = [var for var in model_vars if 'discriminatorA' in var.name]
            g_A_vars = [var for var in model_vars if 'generatorA2B' in var.name]
            d_B_vars = [var for var in model_vars if 'discriminatorB' in var.name]
            g_B_vars = [var for var in model_vars if 'generatorB2A' in var.name]

            lr = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, None, name='learning_rate')
            optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(lr, beta1=momentum)

            d_A_trainer = optimizer.minimize(da_loss, var_list=d_A_vars)
            d_B_trainer = optimizer.minimize(db_loss, var_list=d_B_vars)
            g_A_trainer = optimizer.minimize(g_loss_a2b, var_list=g_A_vars)
            g_B_trainer = optimizer.minimize(g_loss_b2a, var_list=g_B_vars)

            init_op = tf.global_variables_initializer()
            sess.run(init_op)

            for epoch in range(epochs):
                num_batches = int(min(imagesA.shape[0], imagesB.shape[0]) / batch_size)
                lr_ = lr_initial if epoch < epoch_step else lr_initial*(epochs-epoch)/(epochs-epoch_step)

                for index in range(num_batches):
                    batchA = imagesA[index * batch_size:(index + 1) * batch_size]
                    batchB = imagesB[index * batch_size:(index + 1) * batch_size]
                    batch_images = np.concatenate((batchA, batchB), axis=3)
                    batch_images = np.array(batch_images).astype(np.float32)

                    _, fake_B_t, gen_loss_a2b = sess.run(
                        [g_A_trainer, fake_B, g_loss_a2b],
                        feed_dict={real_data: batch_images, lr: lr_})
                    _, fake_A_t, gen_loss_b2a = sess.run(
                        [g_B_trainer, fake_A, g_loss_b2a],
                        feed_dict={real_data: batch_images, lr: lr_})
                    [fake_A_t, fake_B_t] = pool([fake_A_t, fake_B_t])

                    _, dis_loss_a = sess.run(
                        [d_A_trainer, da_loss],
                        feed_dict={real_data: batch_images,
                                   fake_A_sample: fake_A_t,
                                   fake_B_sample: fake_B_t,
                                   lr: lr_})    
                    _, dis_loss_b = sess.run(
                        [d_B_trainer, db_loss],
                        feed_dict={real_data: batch_images,
                                   fake_A_sample: fake_A_t,
                                   fake_B_sample: fake_B_t,
                                   lr: lr_})
```